# beepbeepboopbeep

Tags: sorting

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lab_07_03 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final int BOOP = 10;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0; //
        int countr = 0;
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] countArray = new int[BOOP];
        System.out.println("Enter integers between 1 and 100: ");
        for (i = 0; i < BOOP; i++) {
            countArray[i] = scnr.nextInt(); // array reads user inputs
            if (countArray[i] == 0) {
                break; // 0 signals end of user input
            }
        }
        for (j = 0; countArray[j] != 0; j++) {
            for (i = 0; countArray[i] != 0; i++) {
                if (countArray[j] == countArray[i]) {
                    countr++; // number of times a number appears in an array
                }
            }
            if (countr > 1) {
                System.out.println(countArray[j] + " occurs " + countr + " times.");
                countr = 0;
            } else {
                System.out.println(countArray[j] + " occurs " + countr + " time.");
                countr = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right now I am trying to sort the array so that it prints the numbers in ascending order, and does not print any duplicate numbers. However this is proving difficult and I suspect it is because my array is of length 100 when only 10 slots are used. My reasoning for this is that the array length is supposed to be determined by the user input. Is there a better way to do this?

with an input of 2 5 6 5 4 3 23 43 2 0 output looks like this:
Enter integers between 1 and 100: 
2 occurs 2 times.
5 occurs 2 times.
6 occurs 1 time.
5 occurs 2 times.
4 occurs 1 time.
3 occurs 1 time.
23 occurs 1 time.
43 occurs 1 time.
2 occurs 2 times.

Comment: Please format that code for readability. Please remember that we're volunteers, and so you should make it *easy* to read your code and thus easy to answer your question.

Comment: `"...my array is of length 100 when only 10 slots are used. My reasoning for this is that the array length is supposed to be determined by the user input. Is there a better way to do this?"` -- yes, don't create the new array object until **after** the user has entered the length value. This way it will be *exactly* the correct length.

Comment: Again, please format your code by indenting each block four spaces, by making sure each line on the same block or the same block level is indented the exact same amount as the others. Yes this is a picky request, but again, we're volunteers, and you want to put in the effort to make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: OK, formatted it for you, but again in the future, this should be your responsibility

Comment: sorry I was working on it but you beat me to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume the range of allowed user values are 1..100 only so we may allocate an array of 100 size where an index will be a user value and value will be an incremented counter. In this case we have natural sorting of user values automatically.

Also I reworked to have unlimited user enters (without BOOP limit), enter until 0:

```
public class Lab_07_03 {
    private static final int MIN_VALUE = 1;
    private static final int MAX_VALUE = 100;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int[] counters = new int[MAX_VALUE + 1];

        System.out.println("Enter integers between " + MIN_VALUE + " and " + MAX_VALUE + ": ");

        while (scnr.hasNext()) {
            final int userValue = scnr.nextInt();

            if (userValue == 0) {
                break; // 0 signals end of user input
            }

            if (userValue < MIN_VALUE || userValue > MAX_VALUE) {
                continue; // ignore all out of range values
            }

            counters[userValue] += 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
            final int counter = counters[i];
            if (counter != 0) {
                System.out.println(i + " occurs " + counter + ((counter > 1) ? " times." : " time."));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

An example of input-outputs:

```
Enter integers between 1 and 100: 
1
2
1
2
100
234
0
1 occurs 2 times.
2 occurs 2 times.
100 occurs 1 time.
```

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to vote and mark one answer as a winner.

Answer (score 1):

Use the tools that are best for the job, don't try to make existing tools do something they're not designed for.

In this case, you have a Collection of the following properties:

1. variable length;
2. sorted output;
3. no duplicates.

In this case, it's better to use a `SortedSet<int>`because it has all those things. If you also need to keep the count of each item you have, use a SortedMap where the first int is the number and the second int is the count of that number. Both of these will immediately sort new items as they come in and only have 1 item with a certain value.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your code to fit with an ArrayList of Integers. Also I have initiated **countr with 1** because each element inside the ArrayList will have **at-least 1 instance**. Read the comments in the code for more clarification

```
public static void main (String args []) {
final int BOOP = 10;// BOOP really got me :P
  int i = 0;  
  int j = 0;  //
  int countr = 1;

  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

   ArrayList<Integer> countArray = new ArrayList();

   System.out.println("Enter integers between 1 and 100: ");

   for(i = 0; i < BOOP ; i++) {
    countArray.add(scnr.nextInt()); //array reads user inputs

    if (countArray.get(i)== 0) {
      break;          //0 signals end of user input

    }

   }

  for (j = 0;j< countArray.size()-1; j++){// you want to ignore that last 0 hence -1
  for (i = j+1;i< countArray.size()-1; i++) {
      if (countArray.get(j) == countArray.get(i)) {
       countr++;   //number of times a number appears in an array
       countArray.remove(i);//Remove that duplicate element
       i--;// if a match is found, stay on the current index because the list was moved by 1 unit
      }

    }

    if (countr > 1) {
     System.out.println(countArray.get(j) + " occurs " + countr + " times. ");
     countr = 1;
    }
    else {
       System.out.println(countArray.get(j) + " occurs " + countr + " time. ");
     countr = 1;
    }
} 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and solved it by passing array size first. This method sets array size from console.

```
int size = scnr.nextInt();
int[] countArray = new int[size];
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Arrays.sort then find the duplicate numbers in the array using for loop

[Arrays sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D))